# Using Await.result crashes Akka HTTP server

Tags: scala, async-await

We have our feed backend running on Akka HTTP server. We have some logic to get arrays of various user groups on each browse feed request. As it is totally request independent (banned users, popular users etc), I optimised it by moving that logic from each request to the start of server and then refreshing it each 5 seconds. That way, I have these things ready, when request comes. I take down the load from Elasticsearch, while improving performance in the same time.

This code improved performances a lot and works fine on my local machine. However, when we deploy to DEV env (services running on Kubernetes), server crashes at the start. Nothing in log, just a crash. Timeout is 5 seconds in Await.result call. Operations are not too heavy, simply executing Elasticsearch get or queries.

Do you have an idea why this is happening? Can it be that app runs out of threads?
I never find an detailed explanation how Await.result works under the hood.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `Await.xxxxxx` anywhere. Its blocking.

Comment: But other than killing the performance, using `Await.result` should not cause any other issues. The problem lies somewhere else in your code or environment setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sarveshseri, but I need it as I explained above. Do you see any other way of doing such a thing as described?

Answer (score -1):

Any other thinking?

I was also trying to avoid usage of blocking Await.result, by calculating this users in scheduler on each 5 seconds. And then I use those values (refreshed every 5 seconds) on each API request. While it works fine on my local machine, on DEV it never gets evaluated.

Did anyone try to use scheduler to refresh actor variable value?